# Testing Moq with Where Throws NotSupportedException

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I am new to Moq and unit testing in asp net. Let me dive straight into it.

My Test Function is the following:

```
namespace OfflineMessagingAPI.Tests
{

    public class MessageTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public void ShouldGetAllMessagesSentByAUser()
        {
            // Arrange Data ----
            MessageRequest Request = new MessageRequest();
            Request.From = "userVIP";

            var listOfMessages = new List<AspNetUserMessage>();
            listOfMessages.Add(new AspNetUserMessage {
                From = Request.From,
                To = "User1",
                Text = "DummyTxt"
            });

            listOfMessages.Add(new AspNetUserMessage
            {
                From = "User2",
                To = Request.From,
                Text = "txt2"
            });

            var TranformedList = listOfMessages.AsQueryable();

            // Setup database mocker
            Mock<BlockedUsersAndMessages> mockRepo = new Mock<BlockedUsersAndMessages>();
            mockRepo.Setup(x => x.AspNetUserMessages.Where(o => o.From == Request.From || o.To == Request.From)).Returns(TranformedList);
            var controller = new MessageController(mockRepo.Object);

            // Act ---
            IEnumerable<AspNetUserMessage> messages = controller.GetAllMessages(Request);

            // Assert ---
            Assert.Equal(messages.AsQueryable(), TranformedList));
        }
    }
}
```

My Where has lambda expression queries as:

```
Where(o => o.From == Request.From || o.To == Request.From)
```

because that's how I call it in the GetAllMessages method.

When I run this test I get the following error:
Message Error

```
  Message: 
    System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: ... => ....Where<AspNetUserMessage>(o => o.From == MessageTests.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.Request.From || o.To == MessageTests.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.Request.From)
    Extension methods (here: Queryable.Where) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.
  Stack Trace: 
    Guard.IsOverridable(MethodInfo method, Expression expression)
    InvocationShape.ctor(LambdaExpression expression, MethodInfo method, IReadOnlyList`1 arguments, Boolean exactGenericTypeArguments)
    ExpressionExtensions.<Split>g__Split|4_1(Expression e, Expression& r, InvocationShape& p)
    ExpressionExtensions.Split(LambdaExpression expression)
    Mock.Setup(Mock mock, LambdaExpression expression, Condition condition)
    Mock`1.Setup[TResult](Expression`1 expression)
    MessageTests.ShouldGetAllMessagesSentByAUser() line 41
```

I can not understand the problem here, any help would be so appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Moq - Non-overridable members may not be used in setup / verification expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56905578/moq-non-overridable-members-may-not-be-used-in-setup-verification-expression)

Comment: Amazingly, when I plugged that error message into a search engine, the result that came up was the question I linked to. Next time, try doing the same.

Comment: Your link does not help a bit and is so your rudeness!! I am trying to mock the entity framework your link has nothing to do with my problem!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58671929/unit-testing-for-extension-method-using-moq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing a little bit here as we don't have enough of the schema, but you can't mock the LINQ `Where` extension directly, you can't mock extension methods.

It sounds like your controller takes a dependency on the repo and you're accessing the `AspNetUserMessages` property of that repo directly. If that is the case, just setup `AspNetUserMessages` with the list of existing items to suit the test. The `Where` invocation in `GetAllMessages` will work as it normally would.

```
mockRepo.Setup(x => x.AspNetUserMessages).Returns(TranformedList);
```

If you want to test that the `Where` invocation is working as expected, create a test where `AspNetUserMessages` has existing items that match the `Where` expression. Then create another that doesn't. Add tests until you're satisfied you've covered the expression.